# nodeJS TLS contains odd characters in data

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl

I am trying to send and receive data from a TLS-secured service using mutual certificate authentication. I am successfully connecting to the service and the response is that I am authorized. I send data to the server and then wire up a 'data' event... I know my data is sent accurately, because I get semi-accurate response data.

The data contains odd characters at the beginning and end of each chunk (and sometimes in the middle).

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=8f2a41305cbe859001f1d54e5e80; Path=/xds; Secure
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 13 Feb 2014 01:53:14 GMT

6c
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope x.........
2000
<ns4:AdhocQueryResponse xmlns:ns2="urn:oasis:names:.........
1485
8425c" objectType="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:.........
0
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
var tls = require('tls');
var net = require('net');

var receiveData = function(sock) {
    var response = '';
    sock.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log("Socket error: " + err);
    });

    sock.on('data', function(d){
        response += d.toString();
    });

    sock.on('end', function() {
        console.log("Done receiving data from via TLS: " + response.length);
        console.log(response);
    });
};

var sendData = function(sock) {
    console.log("Sending request to HIE");

    var req = 'POST ' + path + ' HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Host: localhost\r\n' +
        'Content-Length: ' + data.length + '\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8\r\n' +
        'SOAPAction: "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"\r\n' +
        '\r\n';
    sock.write(req);
    sock.write(data);
};

var options = {
    port: port,
    host: host,
    key: fs.readFileSync(tls_key, encoding='ascii'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(tls_cert, encoding='ascii'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync(tls_ca, encoding='ascii')
};

var sock = tls.connect(options, function() {
    var authorized = sock.authorized;

    if (authorized) {
        console.log("Successfully connected via TLS");
        sock.setKeepAlive(true);
        receiveData(sock);
        sendData(sock);
    } else {
        console.log("Unauthorized to connect via TLS: " + sock.authorizationError);
    }
});
```

Does anyone know why I am getting these odd characters? I've tried setting the sock's setEncoding('utf8'), and that removed my need to .toString() the data. But, that didn't solve the problem of these odd characters.

I figured maybe they were indicators of how much data was in the chunk... but, the "6c" is in the middle of the first chunk. So, I don't think that's it. What's more, is the third chunk has a 0, even though there is a LOT of data sent in that chunk.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You had nearly figured it out! The reason for the numbers in the data is that the response is using chunked transfer encoding, as can be seen in the 'Transfer-Encoding' response header:

> `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`

The numbers before each chunk (the header is not a chunk itself, so the 6c is the first part of the 'data') are the hex values representing the number of bytes being sent in that chunk. The response is terminated by a 0 byte chunk. See the following for more info:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1

Chunked transfer encoding allows data to be returned without knowing exactly how much data will be returned when the response starts. If it is known how much data is going to be returned, then the 'Content-Length' response header should be set accordingly.